# How can I calculate only 10% of the eigenvalues ​of a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pca

```
eigenval, eigenvec = np.linalg.eig(cov_matrix)
```

I can calculate all of the eigenvalues of a matrix with **eig()** function but I need to calculate **10%** of eigenvalues. Is there any function to do it?

Comment: Try scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs and specify k=0.1*cov_matrix.shape[0], https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html

Comment: Depending on which eigenvalues you are looking for, you may also have a look at 'which' and 'sigma' keywords arguments